# How to use font to write musical sheet

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, fonts, opentype

I am trying to make an iOS app that can make possible to write and edit musical sheet.
I was wondering how can I visualise it.
I did not found any complete framework in swift that can make it possible.

But I found this font [bravura](https://github.com/steinbergmedia/bravura), but i did not found any example of use.

This is an OpenType Font.

Reading the [documentation](https://github.com/steinbergmedia/bravura/blob/master/redist/bravura-text.md) I should be able to decide through unicode characters, how to change the position of the next element.
But no it doesn't seem to work. At first I thought it was because of the ligatures as not all editors support it, I'm not a font expert and I could be wrong.

So I used the NSAttributedString class to modify these parameters. But the result is still not what is expected.

This is my code :

```
    textView.font = UIFont(name: "Bravura-Text", size: 40)
    let text = "\u{E014}\u{EB99}\u{E0A4} \u{E014}\u{EB91}\u{E0A4}"
    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Bravura-Text", size: 40)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.ligature : 2
        ]  as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)

    textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

E014 = Displaying a 5 line staff

EB99 = Lower by two staff positions

EB91 = Raise by two staff positions

E0A4 = The black notehead

This is the result :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmtfB.png)

Any suggestions to make it possible to use this font and its features on iOS?

I would like to write a musical sheet like [this one](https://i.pinimg.com/474x/cb/d9/60/cbd9602d2f03de12449d4f895f917e8c--the-band-perry-piano-sheet-music.jpg).

Answer (score 4):

Layout of music notation require higher-level layout rather than just displaying a line of text. (Analogous to Web pages using HTML as high-level layout rather than just lines of text.) Fonts can provide the basic symbols, and all of the basic symbols are encoded in Unicode. But you'll need some library that can read a music-notation markup language and layout the content.

You can probably find the kind of resources you'll need at https://www.w3.org/community/music-notation/